# Copy directories overwriting the target

Tags: docker, artifactory

Is there any way, in artifactory's rest API, to copy a directory, replacing the target with the new copy?

```
POST /api/copy/repo/dirA?to=repo/dirB
```

I would like dirB to be exactly like dirA after that.

In my current use case they are both docker directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a pair of requests:

```
DELETE /repo/dirB
POST /api/copy/repo/dirA?to=repo/dirB
```

As far as I know, deleting the existing directory and copying the new one in its place is the only way to do what you want. Specifically, there's no option you can pass to the copy command that changes its behavior. There isn't really a reason to have one, since nearly everyone expects copied directories to merge into the destination: that's how it works in every filesystem I've heard of, and that's what people are used to.

Comment: Maybe the operation name could be something other than copy. The docker promote endpoint already behaves that way, but it obviously doesn't work for any directory. Anyway, good to know the operation is not supported.